# MySQL subquery select specific column

Tags: mysql

I have a subquery that returns 3 columns. I cannot get rid of them. I want to only use one of the columns for the parent query.

For example.

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id = (SELECT a,id,b FROM table_b LIMIT 1);
```

I want to only get `id` from `table_b`.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id = (SELECT a,id,b FROM table_b LIMIT 1)[id];
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM table_b LIMIT 1); you cannot use like this?

Comment: the query is much more complex, the additional columns i cannot get rid of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how abt this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id =
(select id from
 (SELECT a,id,b FROM table_b LIMIT 1)a);
```

Comment: Lol. Yep. Didn't realize it was that easy

Comment: This was a good solution! I was selecting a value with MAX but needed the ID (and so had to select two columns) in a subquery. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a 
WHERE id IN
    (
        SELECT a FROM tableB limit 1
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM tableB limit 1
        UNION
        SELECT b FROM tableB limit 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_a, (SELECT a,id,b FROM table_b LIMIT 1) temp_b where table_a.id = temp_b.id;
```

Is this result match your mind?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of achieving this is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
inner join 
 (
       SELECT a as id FROM tableB
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM tableB
        UNION
        SELECT b as id FROM tableB
) tempB on (table_a.id=tempB.id)
```